# Capturar ID dinámico con $index AngularJs

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

Estoy intentando crear una variable que tenga su `id` dinámico con el `$index` de la directiva `ng-repeat`, pero no encuentro como lograr esto, este es mi código:

```js
var app = angular.module('myApp', []);
app.controller('myCtrl', function($scope, $http) {

    $scope.itemSlider = [
        {
            id: 0,
            url: "img/img-360-1.jpg"
        },
        {
            id: 1,
            url: "img/img-360-2.jpg"
        }
    ]

    $scope.initFirtItem = function(index) {
        var div = document.getElementById('container'+index);
        console.log(div);
    }

});
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8" />
        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.6.4/angular.min.js"></script>
        <script src="script.js"></script>
    </head>

    <body ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="myCtrl">
        <div ng-repeat="item in itemSlider track by $index">
            <div id="container{{ $index }}" ng-init="initFirtItem($index)"></div>
        </div>
    </body>

</html>
```

Comment: ¿Estás seguro que quieres usar la directiva $index o quieres usar el `id` que tienes en cada item dentro del arreglo `itemSlider`?

Comment: @fredyfx pues cualquiera de los dos me serviría, la idea es hacer el id="container" dinámico

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Creo que lo que pasa es que el elemento no se ha terminado de cargar completamente al momento en que se ejecuta el evento `init`, por tal con colocar un `setTimeout()` de 10 milisegundos basta para que el elemento sea reconocido en la función:

```js
var app = angular.module('myApp', []);
app.controller('myCtrl', function($scope, $http) {

    $scope.itemSlider = [
        {
            id: 0,
            url: "img/img-360-1.jpg"
        },
        {
            id: 1,
            url: "img/img-360-2.jpg"
        }
    ]

    $scope.initFirtItem = function(index) {
        setTimeout(function(){
          console.log(document.getElementById('container'+index));
        }, 10);
    }

});
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8" />
        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.6.4/angular.min.js"></script>
        <script src="script.js"></script>
    </head>

    <body ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="myCtrl">
        <div ng-repeat="item in itemSlider track by $index">
            <div id="container{{ $index }}" ng-init="initFirtItem($index)">Item {{ $index }}</div>
        </div>
    </body>

</html>
```

Comment: me sirvió pero quiero ver mas respuestas, excelente.

Answer (score 1):

También podrías iterar ese `id` que tienes en el `itemSlider`

```js
var app = angular.module('myApp', []);
app.controller('myCtrl', function($scope, $http) {

    $scope.itemSlider = [
        {
            id: 0,
            url: "img/img-360-1.jpg"
        },
        {
            id: 1,
            url: "img/img-360-2.jpg"
        }
    ]

    $scope.initFirtItem = function(index) {
        var div = document.getElementById('container'+index);
        console.log(div);
    }

});
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8" />
        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.6.4/angular.min.js"></script>
        <script src="script.js"></script>
    </head>

    <body ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="myCtrl">
        <div ng-repeat="item in itemSlider">
            <div id="container{{ item.id }}" ng-init="initFirtItem(item.id)"></div>
        </div>
    </body>

</html>
```